# Given node.js version, programmatically determine which npm versions are compatible

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two questions, that are similar:

1. Given a node.js version, is it possible to programmatically determine which npm versions are compatible with it?
2. Given an npm version, is it possible to programmatically determine which node.js versions are compatible with it?

Anyone know which if either is possible?

Comment: Note that it's quite common for an out-of-range npm version to not be compatible with a particular node.js version or vice-versa.

Comment: My initially thinking was that metadata in the npm registry would help achieve this. However, after some poking it revealed: Of the 289 versions of npm available, _(i.e. by running `npm show npm versions` then subsequently running `npm show npm@<semver> engines.node` programmatically for each version)_, 84 of them DO include a semver in the `engines.node` field. Those ranged from `npm@1.1.70` thru to `npm@2.0.0-beta.3` with semvers in `engines.node` field ranging from `>=0.6` to `>=0.8` respectively. The remaining 205 versions, (`npm@2.0.0` thru to `npm@6.1.0`), DO NOT have an `engines` field.

Comment: @RobC yeah thanks...so the engines field of package.json is missing for a lot of NPM versions.... I will file an issue with NPM on Github and link to it below. This might be a hopeless exercise, because I don't think the Node.js executable carries with it any information about which NPM version is compatible with it.

Comment: @RobC here is the ticket I filed with NPM, feel free to add to it, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/21055

Comment: thanks for sharing link to ticket. Yeah, I was somewhat surprised by the lack of `engines` property for versions of _npm_. By contrast the meta for _eslint_ package, (for example), is much more comprehensive. Of the 196 versions available in _npm registry_ only the first 20 versions (`eslint@0.0.4` to `eslint@0.5.1`) DO NOT have an `engines` property. Whilst the other 176, (`eslint@0.6.0` to `eslint@5.0.0-rc.0`), DO have an `engines.node` semver _comparator_ or _comparator sets_ value (ranging from `>=0.10` thru to `>=9.10.0`). Sadly many packages lack any `engines` metadata.

Comment: @RobC can you share your query to read all package.json files "engines" property for NPM? Maybe share that on the Github ticket?

Comment: come to think of it - NPM itself must do this check internally. When you do `npm install -g npm` it must check to see what the latest version is that is still compatible with the current node version.

Comment: Agreed - thought the same thing. However where that info exists remains a mystery to me. Btw. I've tried querying this endpoint: (beware it's large!) [https://replicate.npmjs.com/npm](https://replicate.npmjs.com/npm). It resulted in exact same `engines.node` values as before... The benefit: faster/just one call - instead of 290. The downside: its approx 7-8Mb of json. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/robCam/c0eb1b15ea0861d4557afbd4fb0b476d) the `.sh` for that query.